# Do we need the second "to" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

> For the plasma or serum, here we use the MAYI column to remove the protein and **to** enrich the target compounds.

Do we need the second "to" in this sentence?

Comment: It's a matter of style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this sentence, the second **to** is not necessary. You can have it there or not, the parallelism rule is still not violated.

An example where the second **to** is required is like this:

> For the plasma or serum, here we use the MAYI column to remove the protein **and the fat** and to enrich the target compounds.

In case that there are two things that you want to remove, protein and fat as above for example, then the second **to** is required so that readers know "enrich the target compounds" is the second purpose of using the MAYI column, not the third thing that is to be removed after protein and fat.